# Suppress Ansible warnings or send them to a callback?

Tags: ansible

I'm working with the [ansible-module-hashivault](https://github.com/TerryHowe/ansible-modules-hashivault) module to manage my hashicorp vault. Doing so uses ansible on localhost (primarily), and as such, my playbook is entirely run on localhost. I want all my logs in JSON format, using the callback from [this SO question](https://serverfault.com/questions/835901/ansible-json-output#836181).

I've got everything working, except for one minor annoyance. When I run my playbook, I get the following warnings, which do not go through the callback. I've tried all the env vars with "warning" in them from the docs, and none of those warnings seem to disable them. How can I suppress these or send them to the callback function for formatting?

```
 [WARNING]: Unable to parse /etc/ansible/hosts as an inventory source

 [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
```

Comment: Why is that a problem? It doesn't go to stdout.

Comment: I'm going to run this in ECS, so stdout and stderr will be send to cloudwatch logs, and I'd prefer that all of my logs end up in JSON format for easy querying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning appears for two reasons

- the file `/etc/ansible/hosts` which is the system default inventory
  is missing
- localhost is missing from the inventory file (which does not exist)

To fix, first create a file called `ansible.cfg` inside your ansible playbook directory and put inside

```
inventory = inventory
```

so we have declared we will set your inventory file in a file named `inventory` in the local directory. 
Now create a file `inventory` and put inside

```
[defaults]
localhost ansible_connection=local
```

To declare the localhost target.
That should remove the warning